# Is it possible to restore current project functionality in NetBeans?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8

Older versions of netbeans had the right click option to select the current project as the one to which the run/debug etc. functionality is mapped. Since I work in libraries and dependent projects 99% of the time this was really useful when compared to the current approach of running the project of the current file.

I know I can right click to debug/run or select the project from the project explorer but I'd love to have the old option to work with the current project. Can this be restored via a preference in NetBeans 8+?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are searching "Run / Set Main Project". After you selected a main project (via the run-menu) you can also switch main projects right-clicking on a project in the projects view. Why they are not showing this menu in the contextmenu when no main project is selected, is a mystery to me.

Comment: Thanks! Totally missed that!